# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FUNCTION_NAME' ORA-06550 while migrating to Spring 3.x

Tags: spring, hibernate, plsql, spring-data-jpa, spring-3

I'm working on migration my existing Spring 2.x project to Spring 3.x. I'm facing the below mentioned error,

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FUNCTION_NAME'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I'm providing the correct arguments count, not sure why I'm getting this error. I'm providing the code snippet for database procedure and spring code. Is there anything wrong here which I'm not aware of?

```
   FUNCTION function_name
        (
            input     IN package_name.function_name%TYPE
        )
        RETURN cursors.cursor_name
    AS
        output_cursor     cursors.cursor_name;
    BEGIN
    ...
    ...
    ...
    END function_name;
```

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = FUNCTION_NAME,
    procedureName = "package_name.function_name",
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Long.class),
    },
    hints = @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true"),
    resultClasses = POJO.class),
@Table
public class POJO {
}
```

```
 List<POJO> resultSet = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(FUNCTION_NAME)
          .setParameter(1, 1234L)
          .getResultList();
```